# Find out which Music is currently playing [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Is there a way to find out which music is currently playing in the android Music player ? So I want to catch the title time and maybe the author of this music and show it with Textview. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In concordance with the Android API here:
[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) should be what you are looking for

You can create an `AudioManager` and then call the `isMusicActive` to retrieve a boolean if it is playing.

You can then use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) API and call the `getTrackInfo` method which returns an `Array` of track-related information.

**Edit:**

Also, `MediaPlayer` has an `isPlaying` method which really makes AudioManager rather useless in this scenario.

**[Update]**

For future viewers of this question; when you create a `MediaPlayer` object and call the `getTrackInfo` method; it returns an array `TrackInfo[]`; the API for `TrackInfo[]` and it's methods can also be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.html).

Comment: Thank you this is a really nice answer ! Can I also get Info from youtube videos etc. ? Or is it just for the standard Mediaplayer ?

Comment: I think that MediaPlayer handles both audio and video files since the API denotes that it has a getVideoHeight method I would assume as such. If this answer provided a solution for you please accept it as the correct answer :)